# Code Snippets: Where do I keep them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a tool or process for keeping your functions, selectors and 'for loops' handy and search-able for future use? I use nothing and am re-learning occasionally for a similar problem I've already solved.

background:
I'm progressing into jQuery and Javascript and am starting to see some repeating patterns like building complex selectors, iterations to build JSON menus etc.

But I don't have a computer science background so I feel like I'm missing some fundamental 'code library' part of my daily work.

Comment: which development tool are you using

Comment: TextMate does have a snippet tool; I was curious if there was a larger library tool (hosted?) or some foundation of principals that developers use.

Comment: Be careful that you don't use this tool to hold onto bad habits. Sometimes it's good to have to re-learn things, because you may gain new appreciation as your general experience increases.

Comment: ^^ OK; That's kind of what I was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ultimate in portability, nothing beats a plain text file with the snippets stored in it.

Comment: That's what I use for storing commonly-used-and-commonly-forgotten tricks, methods, functions, and snippets. I have one file for each language I use commonly; I don't just store snippets in them either -- I have whole articles in a couple of them that contain useful general techniques (i.e. I just added BobInc's "How to properly create a Javascript Object" from Stackoverflow into my Javascript snippets file).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tool you use. For example, if you use Eclipse, you can search for Eclipse snippets plugs. I use KomodoEdit, which comes with a great snippets tool already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emacs as your development environment, use yasnippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gist from Github https://gist.github.com/ to store your code snippets.
You can also keep them for yourself or share them publicly.
Good thing about Gist: free, online and option to share or not.